# How can i get the number of views in the Google Youtube API?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

[image]I'm using the YouTube API to very simply fetch some videos and display them in a UITableView in my iPhone app,

The problem is this:

1.Number of views of video always returns null

2.i am not getting the video uploaded name.

Here is my code

```
    NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
    NSString *viewCount=[[[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry statistics]viewCount] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",viewCount); // returns null
    NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you get a string returned in your "`title`" variable?

Comment: no in the title i am getting perfect reasult and i also get the thumbnail image. but i am not able to get the number of views count

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you do not have a valid "`entry`" object, and the way to prove this is to do this:

```
if(entry)
{
    GDataYouTubeStatistics * statistics = [entry statistics];
    if(statistics)
    {
        NSNumber * viewNumber = [statistics videoWatchCount];
        NSLog( @"number of views is %ld", [viewNumber integerValue]);

    } else {
        NSLog( @"entry appears to be valid, but there are no stats with it");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"what do you know, entry is nil");
}
```

Also, looking at the [API on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Clients/YouTube/GDataYouTubeStatistics.h?r=732), it appears that you might want to try "`videoWatchCount`" instead of "`viewCount`".

Comment: GDataYouTubeStatistics * statistics = [entry statistics]; mostly it returns null and if it is then i got number of views is 0

Comment: do you think i have to add something into to GDataQueryYouTube? then they will fetch videoWatchCount

Comment: if "`statistics`" is nil, you're not going to get anything valid in "`videoWatchCount`" or "`viewCount`".

Comment: but in the youtube thats has the numberofviews but in my apps i am not getting so there will be something problem

Answer (score 0):

did you pass a **statistics** part in request?

> The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more video resource properties that the API response will include. The part names that you can include in the parameter value are id, snippet, contentDetails, fileDetails, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, **statistics**, status, suggestions, and topicDetails. If the parameter identifies a property that contains child properties, the child properties will be included in the response. For example, in a video resource, the snippet property contains the channelId, title, description, tags, and categoryId properties. As such, if you set part=snippet, the API response will contain all of those properties. (string)